# How to select from the Cassandra using JSON child object in a column?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

Below is how an entry looks like in the Cassandra:

```
id | address                     | age | family  | name | siblings
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | {'city': 'c1', 'rue': 'r1'} |  23 |      si |   si | {'b', 'd'}
```

I want to `select` based on the city which is a child of JSON in the `address` column:

I am not sure if the following are the correct statements:

```
select address from Persons address.city='f';  
select address.city from Persons ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that cannot be done in Cassandra (at least for now).

One possible option is to change your model to something like

```
 id | city | rue | age | family  | name | siblings
----+------+-----+-------------------------------
  1 |   c1 |  r1 |  23 |      si |   si | {'b', 'd'}
```

then you will be able to execute query:

```
select json city, rue from addresses where city = 'c1';
```

to achieve "ready-to-use" json in result:

```
 [json]
-----------------------------
{"city": "c1", "rue": "r1"}
```